# Discord PHP CURL put request to join guild not working

Tags: php, discord, php-curl

I have been using Discord via PHP to get users to log in to my website. However I am trying to allow users that click a button to join my discord server so I followed the docs and got the gorrect url and made the following code. However I am not getting responses nor are my users being added to the guild. Any suggestions/help?

```
define('BASE_JOIN_URL', 'https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/818873733875236915/members/');

if (get('action') == 'login') {
    putRequest($BASE_JOIN_URL.$_SESSION['userID']);
};

function putRequest($url) {
    $data = array('access_token' => $_session['access_token']);                                                                  
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                       

    $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Authorization: Bot <token>",                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   

    $exec = curl_exec($ch);

    return json_decode($exec);

    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        echo curl_error($ch);
    };
};
```

Comment: I don't think you get "no response". You should be receiving at least a status code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.